# Bulk copy all tables from sql server 2008 to sql server express on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-rds, sql-server-2008-express

I am attempting to copy about 5GB of reference data from a local SQL Server 2008 standard instance to a SQL Server 2008 Express instance on Amazon RDS. (This is a once off import)

Amazon recommend using Bulk Copy for anything larger than ~ 1GB. I have found examples for using bulk copy to copy single tables but not for copying all tables in a database.

Google gives me the following http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176818 but its a bit outdated.

My current plan is to update the above script to do what I need, but wondering if anybody has a better idea.

Comment: Does Amazon not allow you to simply take a backup? Oh, how much simpler this would be.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Not that I can see, doing a restore of a backup to an instance seems to require that the backup file exist on the file system of that instance but with RDS you don't get access to the file system.

Comment: Yeah I've been told that the "backups" RDS supports are not true database backups but SAN snapshots. I wonder if Red-Gate's tool works with RDS. There HAS to be an easier answer than BulkCopy.

Comment: Looks like it handles Azure -> Amazon S3 but nothing else. Bummer. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-azure-backup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard for quick imports - not sure how long a load this size would take, but the tool is super-easy to use.  Get it from [CodePlex](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) and here's a short [screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn6zn_Mcj6Q) on how to use this free tool to do this.

Comment: Looks interesting, trying it now. Also looks like it uses Bulk Copy utility internally.

Comment: Excellent tool, worked perfectly, just for reference it took 1 hour 40 minutes to upload 5GB.